# How to find Frequent Patterns from Conditional FP-tree?

Tags: pattern-matching, classification, data-mining, apriori

Given the FP-tree below:

[image]

For Item E:

Conditional Pattern Base is:

> {B:1, A:1} {B:1, A:1, C:1}

From this Conditional FP-tree is obtained as

> {B:2, A:2}

But how to obtain Frequent patterns from this? And then Closed Frequent sets and Maximal Frequent sets?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the specified minimum support.
Assuming the minimum support is 2:

For item E..

Your conditional base:
{B:1, A:1} {B:1, A:1, C:1}

Your F-List:
{B:2, A:2}

Therefore the frequency Patterns:
E:2, EB:2, EA:2
(This is checked by summing frequency of item in each set and checking it is >= to minimum support.

And then taking the following definitions:

- An itemset  is  closed:  none  of  the  immediate  supersets  have   the  same  support  as  the  itemset
- An  itemset  is  maximal  frequent :  none  of  its  immediate  supersets  is  frequent

You will need to calculate the other conditional bases and check the supersets are in line with the above definitions. E.g. {B, A, C} is a superset of {B, A}.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "**obtain Frequent Patterns**"?

In this example, **{B, A}**, are 2 item sets, that are frequently seen with **E**. This means that, **A** and **B** are frequently present with **E**. the number **'2'** for each item, represent the **support**, means that each item **(A and B)** seen **'2'** time with item **'E'**